# Get nested JSON object safely

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I've a nested JSON file `json.loads(f)` :

f :

```
 {
     "obj1" : {
         "obj2" : [
        ... more objects
         ]
      }
    }
```

Right now if i want to get nested object I first get obj1, check if its not None, and then get obj2

However this gets messy if I've many nested objects :
obj1 -> obj2[0] -> obj3 -> obj4[0] .....

How can I get the nested object safety without checking for presence of each object? Is there something like XPath in Python for JSON?
They could return None if any object is not found.

Comment: What do you expect to get when one of the keys or indices does not exist? You can use a `try..except` to catch all value errors.

Comment: @Selcuk They could return None if any object is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to handle this in Python is to use [`try...except`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) and catch the specific error, in this case a `KeyError`. If there is a possibility you will also be indexing into a list, you can also catch the `IndexError`.

For example:

```
d = {
    "obj1" : {
        "obj2" : [1, 2, 3]
    }
}

# Good keys
try:
    l = d['obj1']['obj2']
except KeyError:
    l = None
    
print(l)
# [1, 2, 3]

# Bad Keys
try:
    l = d['obj10']['obj100']
except KeyError:
    l = None
    
print(l)
# None

# Bad Index
try:
    l = d['obj1']['obj2'][20]
except (KeyError, IndexError):
    l = None
    
print(l)
# None
```

This is a pattern often called [EAFP
Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html)